# Java program recursion is not working

Tags: java, math, recursion

I am trying to produce a series of sum of digit of previous terms 
https://oeis.org/A004207

1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 23, 28, 38, 49, 62, 70, 77, 91, 101, 103, 107, 115, 122, 127,

This is the code I have got

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Problem {
        public static int getDigitSum(int number) {
            int total = 0;
            while ( number>0) {
                total +=  total + number%10;
                number = number /10;         


        }
      return total;
    }


    public static int getSum(int number) {
    if ((number == 0) || (number == 1)) // base cases
      return number;
    else
      // recursion step
      return getSum(getDigitSum(number - 1)) +  getSum(number - 2);
  } 

    public static void main( String s []) {
        int sum =0, difference=1, previous =1, last;
        //ArrayList <Integer> sum_list =  new ArrayList <Integer>();
        //sum_list.add(prevous);
        for (int i = 1; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.println(getSum(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This code produce wrong output

```
    1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: Those people  that down vote, please comment the reason for down voting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't expect an answer from anyone.

Comment: @AndyTurner  1+1+2+4+8+16 , where 16 = { 1+6 }= 7

Comment: @AndyTurner I think karu means: I don't expect you to write working code for me, but can you explain why my code doesn't work?

Comment: FAQ tells you why the downvotes: "Why isn't my code working?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very hard to say what exactly is wrong with your code, but it does not follow formula:

> For n>1, a(n) = a(n-1) + sum of digits of a(n-1).

so, you code should look like this:

```
public static int getDigitSum(int number) {
    int total = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        total += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}

public static int getSum(final int number) {
    if (number <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        final int sum = getSum(number - 1); // a(n-1) from formula
        return sum + getDigitSum(sum); // sum of digits of a(n-1) from formula
    }
}
```

so, when you start from 0:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(getSum(i));
}
```

you will see:

```
1
1
2
4
8
16
23
28
38
49
62
```

two main problems with your code:

1. `total +=  total + number%10;` double sum
2. `getSum(number - 2)` should use -1

Comment: Where is the problem then ?

Comment: @karu you've implemented wrong formula

Comment: Ok. I got it now. I did´t understand where was the recursion failing.